# How to give input to MySql connector through Python

Tags: python, mysql

By using mysql-connector-python package

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
new_pin = int(input("Enter Pin Number:"))
Pins_Entry = "INSERT INTO ATM_DEMO_PINS(PIN) VALUES(%s)"  # Middle Program 1
mycursor.execute(Pins_Entry, new_pin)
mydb.commit()
```

Showing Error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a perennial error here on SO, but you need to obtain a cursor with the prepared statement mode turned on:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor(prepared=True)     # change is HERE
new_pin = int(input("Enter Pin Number:"))
Pins_Entry = "INSERT INTO ATM_DEMO_PINS(PIN) VALUES(%s)"  # Middle Program 1
mycursor.execute(Pins_Entry, (new_pin,))
mydb.commit()
```

The error you are seeing would be consistent with MySQL parsing the query with `%s` being a literal part of the query, rather than a placeholder.

Comment: I don't think having `prepared=True` or not makes a difference in this particular case, but passing a non-collection (the integer itself, instead of a collection of argument(s)) as the second argument to `execute()`.

Comment: Looking at it a bit closer, at least the version of mysql-connector-python from 4 years ago has the behaviour that if given other than list, tuple, dict, or None it will simply ignore the second argument and pass the statement forward as is.

Comment: @IljaEverilä You were right about the tuple issue and I have corrected it, good catch.  I stand by what I said about opening with a prepared statement though.

Comment: Of course, that's another issue that I've no experience about :)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in this line

```
mycursor.execute(Pins_Entry, new_pin)
```

It will be like this

```
mycursor.execute(Pins_Entry%new_pin)
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
new_pin = int(input("Enter Pin Number:"))
Pins_Entry = "INSERT INTO ATM_DEMO_PINS(PIN) VALUES(%s)"  # Middle Program 1
mycursor.execute(Pins_Entry%new_pin)#"INSERT INTO ATM_DEMO_PINS(PIN) VALUES(new_pin)"
mydb.commit()
/*
in string manipulation %s is use for input your variable to string so #it work as this
a=12
if use like this
print('my number %s',a)=>my number %s 12
but using this give your proper query
print('my number %s'%a)=>my number 12   
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do the following:

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
new_pin = int(input("Enter Pin Number:")) 
Pins_Entry = f"INSERT INTO ATM_DEMO_PINS(PIN) VALUES('{new_pin}')" 
mycursor.execute(Pins_Entry) 
mydb.commit()
```